# Prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \int_{a}^{b}f_{n}=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Suppose
$f_{n}:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are continuous,  $f_{n}\rightarrow 0$ pointwise and $\exists C: \int_{a}^{b}f^{2}_{n} <C$ $\forall n$. I need to prove that $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \int_{a}^{b}f_{n}=0$.

My attemp. Using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $$\int_{a}^{b}|f_{n}| \leq \int_{a}^{b}1 \int_{a}^{b} f_n^{2}=(b-a)^{1/2}\int_{a}^{b}f_{n}^{2}.$$ So, it's enough to prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{a}^{b}f_{n}^{2}=0$.

Let's denote $g_{n}:=f_{n}^{2}$, $M_{n}:=\max_{x\in [a,b]}(g_{n}(x))$. I want to show that $\{M_{n}\}$ is bounded (to use  Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem). Suppose $\forall k \exists N: n>N \Rightarrow |M_{n}|>k.$  $g_{n}(x_{n})=M_{n}$, $g_{n}(x)$ is continious $\Rightarrow (\exists U_{n}: x \in U_{n} \Rightarrow g_{n}(x)>k$). So, $k\mu(U_{n})<\int_{U}g_{n}<C$. There should be some contradiction...

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You can't prove that $\int_a^b f_n^2\to 0$, because it's not necessarily true. Take, for instance, a sequence of 'spike' functions on $[0,1]$, where $f_n^2$ is a spike centred on $\frac{1}{n}$, of height $n$ and width $\frac2n$. Then $\int_0^1 f_n^2=\frac12$ for all $n$, although $f_n\to 0$ pointwise.

Comment: @TonyK Thank you

Comment: Correction: I meant of course $\int_0^1 f_n^2=1$.

Comment: Egorov's theorem should help here.

Answer (score 1):

Following @gerw 's hint of Egorov's theorem:

Let $\epsilon>0$. Then there exists a measurable set $A\subset [a,b]$ such that $m(A)<\epsilon$ and $f_n$ converges to $f\equiv 0$ uniformly on $B:=[a,b]\backslash{A}$.

On $B$, by definition of uniform convergence, there exists $N$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|f_n(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x \in B$ and all $n\geq N$. Hence,
$$
\left|\int_B f_n \right|\leq \int_B |f_n|\leq \epsilon\, m(B)\leq \epsilon (b-a).
$$
On $A$, we have
\begin{align}
\left|\int_A f_n \right|\leq \int_A |f_n|\leq \sqrt{m(A)}\sqrt{\int_A f_n^2}\leq \sqrt{\epsilon}\sqrt{C}.
\end{align}

Comment: Could you explain please why $\int_A |f_n|\leq \sqrt{m(A)}\sqrt{\int_A f_n^2}\leq \sqrt{\epsilon}\sqrt{C}$ (I understand only that we can use this inequality for $A=[a,b]$)

Comment: Do you know Holder's inequality or Cauchy Schwarz in general?